# Gerrit publish patch on non local change

Tags: git, gerrit

I have published a change to the Gerrit of a project I'm working on, and have done a few patches since. I'm now on another machine however, and don't have access to my previous one. The project uses Google's git-repo tool. I want to somehow get the changes locally, modify them and publish a new patch on the current change without creating a new one.

The Gerrit in question is for [LineageOS](https://review.lineageos.org/) and I have used [these instructions](https://wiki.lineageos.org/submitting-patch-howto.html) to publish my changes.

I am still rather new to Gerrit so I'll be glad if you could also explain what the various steps do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are on a new machine, you need to complete the [initial setup](https://wiki.lineageos.org/submitting-patch-howto.html#initial-setup-1) before you can have access to the project repository in Gerrit.

If you need to build the code, you may have to repo-sync all the projects. If not, you can clone only the project you are working on.

```
git clone <repository url>
```

However, the cloned repository is not useable so far because it doesn't contain the commit corresponding to the newest patchset of the change yet. The patchset is still open, not submitted and merged to the target branch, so it can't be cloned by default. You want to amend it and create a new patchset. Now you need to fetch the commit and check it out. On the change page, you can find `Download` on the top right corner. Click and you can see `Checkout`. Copy the commands.

```
cd <local repo>
# paste and run the copied commands
# the commands are git fetch and git checkout, like git fetch <url> refs/changes/xx/xxxx/x && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
# make changes
git add <changed files>
git commit --amend
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/<branch>
```

Please note that do not modify or delete the change id in the commit message, otherwise a new change instead of a new patchset will be created. If you do by mistake, you can run `git commit --amend` again and replace the new change id with the original one. Besides, if you care about the cost of network and disk space, you can use `git init foo && cd foo && git remote add origin <repository_url>` instead of `git clone <repository url>`, and add `--depth=2` in the copied `git fetch`.

Gerrit supports online edit. So if you want to make some minor changes, you can also edit the latest patchset to create a draft and then publish it on the change page. You can find the `Edit` button above the file list.